# Error while working on JSP MVC and reading from a file in model java classes

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller

I am working on a project and using **JSP MVC**. While reading from a file in model classes(.java files in mvc.model pakage) I get an error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Models\en-ner-person-name.bin (The
>   system cannot find the path specified)

The Path is chosen while running as a java Application. I have been surfing on the net for 3-4 days but couldn't found the solution. please any help me out..

Comment: provide your code in model class please.

Comment: please, post your tried code.

Comment: `code` try {
   model = new TokenNameFinderModel(new FileInputStream("Models/en-ner-person-name.bin"));
   //en-ner-person-test.bin is a self trained model for names
   nameFinder = new NameFinderME(model);
  } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`code`

Comment: Here is the directory structure: